# An exception was thrown by the type initializer for TimerManager, Azure on Mono

Tags: c#, linux, azure, mono, azureservicebus

I am getting this exception when trying to create `NamespaceManager` to create a `Queue` in my `Service Bus` instance.

`An exception was thrown by the type initializer for TimerManager`

I have read that `CreateWaitableTimer` is not available on Linux but it makes me wonder how anyone else has managed to get `Service Bus Queues` working on Linux using Mono.

PS. I am using `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` nuget library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue raised for Azure IoT SDK but essentially links to similar nature as both SDKs internally use `CreateWaitableTimer`

Issue link on [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues/64)